# Using SUMIF for a list of conditions

Tags: excel, vba, csv, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

Trying to use SUMIF to group data by class:

I have a data set that looks like this:

[image: dataset]

I also have a list of properties:

[image: properties]

Now I want the sum of `Class A` `Class B` & `Class C` over time.

Thus in a new column `(Cell I2)` I typed the formula: `=SUMIF($B$1:$H$1,$N$2:$N$8,$B2:$H2)` and the result should be `116`, however it is not?

[image: excel doc]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you how it would be `116`?

Comment: Company1,2 and 4 are class A `=45+30+41=116`

Answer (score 1):

Change the labels in cells I1 to K1 to be just A, B and C.

Then you can use in cell I2

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B2:$H2,--(INDEX($O$2:$O$8,MATCH($B$1:$H$1,$N$2:$N$8,0))=I$1))
```

Copy across and down. This approach works in Excel 365 with the new Dynamic Array functions, which currently is only available to Insider versions. Proof in this screenshot:

[image]

For older versions of Excel, it will be easiest to insert a row below the company name and add the class there. Then you can use a simple Sumif of Sumifs formula. Here's the Sumifs formula used in the screenshot with Excel 2010:

```
=SUMIFS($B3:$H3,$B$2:$H$2,I$1)
```

[image]

**Edit two**: credit to Tim Heng for supplying this formula to go into cell I2, copy across and down. Works in any version of Excel.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$H$1=$N$2:$N$8)*($O$2:$O$8=I$1)*$B2:$H2)
```

Comment: Thank you, however I am receiving a `#VALUE!` error?

Comment: I added an alternative to my answer.

Comment: Couldn't you have used Right(I$1,1) instead of I$1 to fully meet OP's request?

Comment: @VBasic2008 It is most likely that the sample of "Class A" is not the real name and that it may be "apples", "cucumbers", "ozelots" instead. I'm trying to look beyond the simplified data sample to a practical solution.

Comment: I am fairly sure I have excel365, any idea why the first code won't work?

Comment: I have the Insider build of Office 365. You may have Office 365, but there are different releases. I've reached out to the MVP community and I will update my answer with a solution that works for your version.

Comment: I've added a formula supplied by fellow MVP Tim Heng. This will work in any version of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

## Five Ranges Madness

[image]

### In Excel

In cell I2 use the following formula:

```
=SFive($B2:$H2,$B$1:$H$1,$N$2:$N$8,$I$1:$K$1,$O$2:$O$8)
```

and copy/paste where you need it.

### In VBA

```
Function SFIVE(SumRange As Range, CompanyH As Range, CompanyV As Range, _
        ClassH As Range, ClassV As Range) As Double ' As Long if whole numbers.

    Dim vntSumH As Variant    ' Horizontal Sum Array
    Dim vntCompH As Variant   ' Horizontal Company Array
    Dim vntCompV As Variant   ' Vertical Company Array
    Dim vntClassH As Variant  ' Horizontal Class Array
    Dim vntClassV As Variant  ' Vertical Class Array
    Dim strClass As String    ' Current Class
    Dim strCompany As Variant ' Current Company

    Dim j As Long   ' Horizontal Class Range Column Counter
    Dim i As Long   ' Vertical Class and Vertical Company Array Row Counter
    Dim k As Long   ' Horizontal Company and Sum Array Row Counter

    vntSumH = SumRange    ' Copy Horizontal Sum Range to array.
    vntCompH = CompanyH   ' Copy Horizontal Company Range to array.
    vntCompV = CompanyV   ' Copy Vertical Company Range to array.
    vntClassH = ClassH    ' Copy Horizontal Class Range to array.
    vntClassV = ClassV    ' Copy Vertical Class Range to array.

    ' Loop through columns of Horizontal Class Range.
    For j = 1 To ClassH.Columns.Count
        ' Check column of "Input Cell" against column of Horizontal Class Range.
        If Application.ThisCell.Column = ClassH.Column + j - 1 Then
            ' Assign only Class (last character) to Current Class.
            strClass = Right(vntClassH(1, j), 1)
            ' Loop through rows of Vertical Class (Company) Array.
            For i = 1 To UBound(vntClassV)
                ' Check if value of current row in Vertical Class Array
                ' is equal to Current Class.
                If vntClassV(i, 1) = strClass Then
                    ' Assign value of current row in Vertical Company Array
                    ' to Current Company.
                    strCompany = vntCompV(i, 1)
                    ' Loop through columns of Horizontal Company (Sum) Array.
                    For k = 1 To UBound(vntCompH, 2)
                        ' Check if value of current column in Horizontal
                        ' Company Array is equal to Current Company.
                        If vntCompH(1, k) = strCompany Then
                            ' Check if current column in Sum Array contains
                            ' a number.
                            If IsNumeric(vntSumH(1, k)) Then
                                ' Add value of current column in Sum Array
                                ' to SFIVE.
                                SFIVE = SFIVE + vntSumH(1, k)
                            End If
                            ' If you will allow multiple occurrences of
                            ' a Company in Horizontal Company Array (Range),
                            ' you will have to outcomment the following
                            ' "Exit For" line.
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
            Exit For ' Stop searching because these are unique values.
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, does this only work for three class types?

Comment: @user11015000: It works for as many you like, you just have to adjust the range e.g. you would write **Class D** into **L1** and in the formula instead of **$K$1** would use **$L$1**. The code is pretty flexible e.g. you could add Companies or expand the Company and Class columns etc. You just have to adjust the ranges in the formula accordingly.